# How to change color of QMainWindow borders and title bar?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qmainwindow, qtstylesheets

The `QMainWindow` below is assigned a dark-gray background-color using QSS.
I would also like to change the color of the borders and the color of the title bar.

How to achieve control of the appearance of the `QMainWindow` borders and titlebar?

I would like to know how to change their colors and how to control the borders width and the title-bar's height.

[image]

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

appStyle="""
QMainWindow{
background-color: darkgray;
}
"""

class GUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GUI, self).__init__()  
        self.setStyleSheet(appStyle)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    if not QApplication.instance(): app=QApplication([])
    w=GUI() 
    w.setStyleSheet(appStyle)
    w.show() 
    w.raise_()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To my knowledge you cannot (on Windows maybe with some special OS dependent calls) modify the borders and header of a top-level widget (real window on the desktop) in Qt because these are delivered from the operating system.

You can however, set the widget `frameless` and add borders for yourself.

Example:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
app.setStyleSheet('QMainWindow{background-color: darkgray;border: 1px solid black;}')

w = QtGui.QMainWindow()
w.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
w.show()

app.exec_()
```

And looks like

[image]

You see that unfortunately the usually header bar vanishes, so no dragging, no resizing, no closing or minimizing. This then all must be implemented yourself. See for example [How can I handle events in the titlebar and change its color etc ?](http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_can_i_handle_events_in_the_titlebar_and_change_its_color_etc).

Answer (score 1):

This can be implemented in QT C++ by detecting current system theme from Windows registry and applying the Dark Window hints. A dark style in addition to this can make dark light window modes.

A sample project demonstrating this is shared here if it helps to adapt

https://envyen.com/posts/2021-10-24-QT-Windows-Dark-theme/